# jquery ajax request error on spring scala mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, scala

**Jquery Ajax request**

```
<script>




 function onSubModulesSelect(id, checkbox) {
     alert(id)
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'selectedSubModulesRow.html',
                data : ({
                    checkBoxId : id
                })
            });
        } 
    }

  </script>\\\
```

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value =Array( "/selectedSubModulesRow.html"))
  @ResponseBody
    def selectedSubModuleRow(@RequestParam checkBoxId: String) {
    println("Reached..!")
    if (checkBoxId != null) {

          println( checkBoxId )

        }
    }
```

When i press  submit button it cannot parse to controller method ...browser console show some errors

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/resources/demos/style.css
GET http://localhost:8080/learnware/teacher/selectedSubModulesRow.html?checkBoxId=q1 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.9.1.js:8526
```

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration for the dispatcher make sure you map the static resources:

```
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving
up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

This will cause the dispatcher servlet to ignore requests for anything within the `resources` directory where all static content such as js,css and images should be placed.

Comment: @jijeshAj  I really think you need to add the resources configuration if you don't already have it.

Comment: You should have a configuration file that defines all of your beans associated with the dispatcher, put the resources configuration in that file.  Then make sure all of your static resources such as js/css/images are within a directory named resources under your web root